# Why do some really bad questions have 1 undelete vote?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, vote-to-undelete

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714968/read-this-to-be-thoroughly-enlightened) is an extreme example [requires 10k privs to view].

Are these likely to be undelete votes from the very user who asked the question?

Comment: Probably the OP.

Comment: Democracy, they have a right to their vote

Comment: Probably hats.  I've seen a lot of strange undelete votes, and I blamed it on the hat you get for casting a reopen vote.

Comment: Funny that external crawler/copycat [was fast enough to index it](http://bighow.net/7994903-Read_this_to_be_thoroughly_enlightened.html) before it got deleted! :)

Comment: OP even had the audacity to edit and add more goop to the post ...  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20714968/revisions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are these likely to be undelete votes from the very user who asked the question?

Probably. As long as it wasn't deleted by a moderator, any 10k user, as well as the OP, can vote to undelete the post. The OP likely pushed the button thinking the post would be instantly undeleted and was disappointed to see that's not how the system works.